# GWT SafeHTML & ActiveX ClassID

Tags: object, gwt, activex

Is it possible to use GWT's SafeHTML templates to define an activeXControl?   If I don't use the SafeHTML mechanism, it all works fine....however if I try to use SafeHTML it replaces my input classid with a "#".

Is SafeHTML blocking the use of classid?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SafeHtml sanitizes URLs that you try to "inject" into attributes that it knows are of type URL. This sanitization only accepts HTTP, HTTPS, FTP and MAILTO.

You can use other URLs but you have to explicitly say they're *safe* to use, by passing them as `SafeUri` instances. You'll create such instances using `UriUtils.fromTrustedString` or `UriUtils.fromSafeConstant`.